# Too much HTTP output connect logs

Tags: logging, http

I have about new 100 records per second in syslog, kern.log and debug. All they are similar and look like

```
kernel: [2927191.803601] new HTTP output connect: IN= OUT=venet0 SRC=2a03:f480:0001:0017:0000:0000:0000:00a6 DST=2a00:bdc0:0004:0008:0001:0000:0508:0109 LEN=198 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=37871 DPT=443 WINDOW=225 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

Every day I have to clean up logs because they are taking over all server free space.
How can I figure out what causes these logs?

Comment: You might have to reduce the debugging levels of your log files. What *nix version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem like the logs generated from iptables, chek the output of :

```
iptables -nvL
```

There should be some rule that jumps to log, example:

```
0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 LOG flags 0 level 4
```

If you don't need this logs drop the relative iptables rule. For the exact commands post the output of:

#### Updated

```
iptables -nvL | grep LOG
```

Comment: It gives me an error. 

`# iptables -nvL | grep LOG output`

`grep: output: No such file or directory`

Comment: There was a typo in my command, corrected